# Devise Invitable - Separate Invite Forms for User Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two different types of user groups for my app. 'Customer' and 'Staff'. When the admin is sending an invite, I am trying to create different forms for both groups to ensure appropriate inputs for each are filled up.

Please let me know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions could be to add a column (let's say user_type), which could be let's say a `string`. Then you would need to set that column to `'customer'` or `'staff'` when pre-creating a user (inviting in your case).

Then, you could create two partials for registrations forms: `_staff_form.html.erb` and `_customer_form.html.erb`. When rendering a user registration form you then could simply render an appropriate partial for the user type like `= render "#{@user.user_type}_form"`

Using a similar approach you could have your validations set up. In your `user` model you could add

```
validate :fields_by_user_type

def fields_by_user_type
  if user_type == 'staff'
    return if department.present?
    errors.add(:department_id, "Staff member must have an department assigned")
  else
    return if credit_card.present?
    errors.add(:credit_car, "Customer must have a credit card")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I created another Devise model and now I have the following structure - 
- Staff Model (Devise)
- Users model (Devise)

However, my admin is a part of the Users model and is only able to invite Users and not able to invite Staff. How to let the admin invite both ?